# Find $f(x)$, when $\left[f''(x)\right]^2\cdot f(x)=\left[f'(x)\right]^3,\ \forall x\in[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function with
>   $f''(x)>0,\ \forall x\in[0,1]$, $f(0)=f'(0)=1$ and
>   $\left[f''(x)\right]^2\cdot f(x)=\left[f'(x)\right]^3,\ \forall
>  x\in[0,1]$. Find $f(x)$.

I am not sure how I can manipulate the third equality to derive $f(x)$. Any hint?

Comment: Hint: By the condition, $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ are all positive on $[0, 1]$. Now check that the given equation is equivalent to $$ \frac{f''}{\sqrt{f'}} = \frac{f'}{\sqrt{f}}. $$ Then integrate both sides and use the initial condition to conclude that $f = f'$. Finally, check that this gives $f(x) = e^x$.